# OpenCV - Java : inRange function

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I have my image `mRgba` and when I do this :

```
Core.inRange(mRgba, B1, B2, mRgba);
```

I have the result that I expect : all my RGBA image is thresholded between B1 and B2.

Now I want to do this :

```
Mat roi = mRgba.submat(rect);
Core.inRange(roi, B1, B2, roi);
```

And it's not apply on my area rectangle, I try everything since 3 hours I can't find a solution...

Comment: I accept C++ code or anything, just an explanation...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, maybe everybody doesn't care, but after many tries, i found the answer.

```
Mat roi = new Mat();
roi = mRgba.submat(rect);
Mat roiTmp = roi.clone();

Imgproc.cvtColor(roiTmp, roiTmp, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);

Core.inRange(roiTmp, B1, B2, roiTmp);

Imgproc.cvtColor(roiTmp, roi, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA);
```